# Flask suddenly not connecting to db

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I had a huge working flask application running in an ec2 server with AWS RDS. I am using Apache with mod-wsgi. Suddenly all the URIs which make queries return errors.

I cannot spot why I started getting an "OperationalError: no such table: users u'SELECT users....'

The table is shown in the MySQL show tables. Further if I log into the server, acvitavate the virtualenv, and from the python console run:

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from myapp import create_app
from myapp.extensions import db
app=create_app()
manager=Manager(app)
ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()
```

I can access the user table and others. So what is going on here?

I am using two different configurations (development/production). This is done through the use of an environment variable. If I ran the code above in the production server, then I get the production configuration. How can I start to debug the problematic connection?

The app.wsgi file reads like this

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/myapp")
from myapp import create_app
application = create_app()
```

and then create_app is called, and apparently it reads the correct configuration. In particular, it will import and run

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

and then configure it

```
db.init_app(app)
```

The apache2 error log reads like this:

```
mod_authz_core.c(802): [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:29629] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
mod_authz_core.c(802): [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:29629] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
mod_authz_core.c(802): [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:29629] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
mod_authz_core.c(802): [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:29629] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
mod_wsgi (pid=6780, process='', application='ec2-XXX.XX.XX.XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com|'): Reloading WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=6780): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-    py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/var/www/myapp/myapp/frontend/views.py", line 71, in index
#current_app.logger.debug('debug')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.0-    py2.7.egg/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 431, in paginate
items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-    linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2320, in all
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-    linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2453, in     _execute_and_instances
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 436, in do_execute
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: users u'SELECT users.password AS users_password, users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.openid AS users_openid, users.activation_key AS users_activation_key, users.created_time AS users_created_time, users.avatar AS users_avatar, users.role_code AS users_role_code, users.status_code AS users_status_code, users.user_detail_id AS users_user_detail_id, users.followers AS users_followers, users.following AS users_following \\nFROM users\\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' (10, 0)
```

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for this: there was a change made in the configuration that changes which database you are pointing at (a development versus production DB), you changed the default schema for the user that you log in as and so the table is not found by default, etc.. Unfortunately the only code you've provided is code which, according to you, works. There is too little information in this post for someone to be able to determine the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark Hildreth. Adding some production vs development cfg information. Let me know if you want me to add any information.

Answer (score 0):

There was a sequence of details that led to the problem. By design, the default configuration is loaded first and then it is overwritten with the line

```
app.config.from_envvar("PRODUCTION_CFG",silent=True)
```

The problem was that the environment variable was set in the session in which I was using the bash, but not in the session were the server was running. I fixed it by using app.config.from_pyfile instead.